# How can I avoid 400 (Bad Request) from ajax PUT

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, bad-request

So I got this JavaScript that is supposed to send some data with PUT to my server with ajax.

```
var payload = 'id=' + id + '&brand=' + brand + '&model=' + model + '&country=' + country + '&number=' + number + '&alkohol=' + alkohol + '&volume=' + volume + '&price=' + price + '&comment=' + comment;

var fixedPayload = payload.split(' ').join('+'); // replace blanks with +

$.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/drinks/' + fixedPayload,
        // data: fixedPayload, this does not work either
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Update was successfull!');
        }
    });
```

**This is on the server**

```
app.put('drinks/:id', (req, res) => {

    let id = req.params.id;
    var data = {
        brand: req.body.brand,
        model: req.body.model,
        country: req.body.country,
        number: req.body.number,
        alkohol: req.body.alkohol,
        volume: req.body.volume,
        price: req.body.price,
        comment: req.body.comment
    };
    Drink.findByIdAndUpdate(id, data, function(err, drink) {
        if (err) throw err;

        res.send('Drink updated - '+drink.model);
        });
});
```

**This is what I get**

> jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 PUT
>   http://localhost:3000/drinks/?5c1b873a6a0a5d3ae0342f01&brand=L%C3%A4sk&model=Cola&country=Sverige&number=999&alkohol=0%&volume=33+cl&price=20&comment=Cola+asd
>   404 (Not Found)

**Console.log(fixedPayload)**

> ?5c1b873a6a0a5d3ae0342f01&brand=Läsk&model=Cola&country=Sverige&number=999&alkohol=0%&volume=33+cl&price=20&comment=Cola+asd

What seems to be the issue?
I have also tried to send an Object instead of a string but with the same result

**Solved it**

**AJAX**

```
package = {
    brand: brand,
    model: model,
    country: country,
    number: number,
    alkohol: alkohol,
    volume: volume,
    price: price,
    comment: comment        
};




$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: `http://localhost:3000/drinks/${id}`, // changed it here
    data: package,
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Update was successfull!');
        window.location = "http://localhost:3000/";
    }
});
```

Comment: your url contanis / before ?.

Comment: The fixed example is (manually) doing form encoding. Maybe the dynamic version is sending JSON but the server is expected form encoding?

Comment: Also, there output you quote says 404 status (not found) but the title says 400 (bad request): which is it? (They do mean different things.)

Comment: maybe add `headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'}` to jquery.ajax?

Comment: Yes I started to fiddle with the code, var payload = '?' + id + '&brand'... gives a 404

Answer (score 0):

Here are the problems with your code :

- your endpoint `drinks/:id` requires a path variable, `id`, which isn't set since you are appending to `drinks/` a query string on your client : `'http://localhost:3000/drinks/' + fixedPayload`
- you pass you params as a query string when the server expects them to be in the body. `brand: req.body.brand`

This should be something like :

```
var payload = '?brand=' + brand + '&model=' + model + '&country=' + country + '&number=' + number + '&alkohol=' + alkohol + '&volume=' + volume + '&price=' + price + '&comment=' + comment;

var fixedPayload = payload.split(' ').join('+'); // replace blanks with +

$.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/drinks/' + id,
        data: fixedPayload,
        // data: fixedPayload, this does not work either
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Update was successfull!');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Oh yeah I just copied some other code and totally missed that it was body instead of params. 

However, I don't follow on the first problem. Is it supposed to be 'http://localhost:3000/drinks/' + id;
data: fixedPayload; // without id in it?
#noob

Comment: Okey, I have that exact code now and I get a 400 bad request

Comment: do you have body-parser installed and setup correctly on the server side ? does jquery send the data as url-encoded ?

Comment: body-parser should be working properly.
I have these lines that I don't really know what they do.
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded( { extended: false }));

How can I check if if jquery sends data url-encoded?

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is malformatted, I do belive the `id` which is part of your URL parameters should be part of the path instead. In your example: http://localhost:3000/drinks/5c1b873a6a0a5d3ae0342f01?brand=...

Answer (score 0):

Creating HTTP requests is tricky (for instance, a `%` character needs encoding, which your code doesn't do: this could well be the reason for the 400 error). jQuery is good at doing it for you. You're probably best letting it take care of creating the request string by passing an object rather than a string.

```
var payload = {
    id: id,
    brand: brand,
    model: model,
    country: country,
    number: number,
    alkohol: alkohol,
    volume: volume,
    price: price,
    comment: comment
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/drinks/',
    data: payload,
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Update was successfull!');
    }
});
```

Moreover, your serverside code expects a request in the format `drinks/:id`, so you probably actually want something like

```
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/drinks/' + id,
```

in your AJAX settings object.

Comment: That gives me a 404. Where would you put the '?' in this example?
Does it have to know the type? Does that matter? (application/json)

Comment: @axlu You don't need to put the `?` in: jQuery will handle anything like that for you. You aren't submitting JSON, so you don't need a `contentType`. My best guess is that you need to change the `url` setting as in my answer.

Comment: Okay, well I tried your code and I still get the error,
jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 PUT http://localhost:3000/drinks/5c1b873… 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
update @ find.js:68
onclick @ (index):1

Comment: @axlu Well, the 400 error is fixed, then! That's a good start. Now you just have to work out why the request isn't being routed properly. The most obvious reason would be not restarting the server, but I'm not an expert on running an Express app.